# range between interval that does not include the first row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a line:

```
sum(purchases) over(partition by category order by value_day range between interval '1' month preceding and current row)
```

If `value_day = Aug 21`, it returns sum from and included July 21 till and included Aug 21, but I need from and included July 22 till and included Aug 21.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. I've written a few queries with this functionality and they work well in Oracle.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a68ce815b3ddecf350267f275af9e432

Comment: If value_day = June 30, do you need to include May 31, or exclude it? Note that with your specification (range between interval '1' month preceding...), the range begins with May 30, not May 31!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression to define the starting point of the window. So you can

- Subtract a month from the current date
- Add a day to it

Giving something like:

```
sum ( purchases ) over (
  partition by category 
  order by value_day 
  range between ( value_day - ( add_months ( value_day, -1 ) + 1 ) ) preceding 
  and current row
)
```

Comment: The OP needs to clarify the task (regardless of any coding solution). `add_months(..., -1)` is not the same as `interval '1' month preceding` - for example if the starting date is June 30, the former will start from May 30 and the latter from May 31. Which one is right depends on the exact requirement and can't be decided without business user input.

Comment: This works! Thank you) I didn't know that you could specify the window when using range.

Comment: @mathguy - true, though the former returns 31st May, right? Also you can't use this trick to subtract month intervals because this can map to invalid dates (e.g. date'2022-05-31' - interval '1' month)

Comment: The "interval" computation in the windowing clause is not the same as in date/timestamp arithmetic. `date '2022-05-31 - interval '1' month` errors out, but in a windowing clause it produces `2022-04-30` just like adding -1 months. However, when you start from 04-30 and range is from that date - interval '1' month, the first date is 03-30, not 03-31 as it would be with `add_months`. `add_months` is different from date/timestamp and interval arithmetic with the `interval '1' month` syntax, and the interval arithmetic in a windowing clause is different from **both**. (Oracle will explain why.)

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Use two windowed functions, your one to add everything from the past month and then subtract a second one that just covers the range you do not want to include; or
- Use a correlated sub-query rather than windowed analytic functions.

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       sum(purchases) over(
         partition by category
         order by value_day
         range between interval '1' month preceding and current row
       ) -
       COALESCE(
         sum(purchases) over(
           partition by category
           order by value_day
           range between interval '1' month preceding and interval '1' month preceding
         ),
         0
       ) AS total1,
       ( SELECT SUM(s.purchases)
         FROM   table_name s
         WHERE  t.category = s.category
         AND    ADD_MONTHS(t.value_day, -1) + INTERVAL '1' DAY <= s.value_day
         AND    s.value_day <= t.value_day
       ) AS total2
FROM   table_name t;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (category, value_day, purchases) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + LEVEL - 1, LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;
```

Outputs:

> | CATEGORY | VALUE_DAY | PURCHASES | TOTAL1 | TOTAL2 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | 1 | 01-FEB-22 | 32 | 527 | 527 |
> | 1 | 02-FEB-22 | 33 | 558 | 558 |
> | 1 | 03-FEB-22 | 34 | 589 | 589 |
> | 1 | 04-FEB-22 | 35 | 620 | 620 |
> | 1 | 05-FEB-22 | 36 | 651 | 651 |
> | 1 | 06-FEB-22 | 37 | 682 | 682 |
> | 1 | 07-FEB-22 | 38 | 713 | 713 |
> | 1 | 08-FEB-22 | 39 | 744 | 744 |
> | 1 | 09-FEB-22 | 40 | 775 | 775 |
> | 1 | 10-FEB-22 | 41 | 806 | 806 |
> | 1 | 11-FEB-22 | 42 | 837 | 837 |
> | 1 | 12-FEB-22 | 43 | 868 | 868 |
> | 1 | 13-FEB-22 | 44 | 899 | 899 |
> | 1 | 14-FEB-22 | 45 | 930 | 930 |
> | 1 | 15-FEB-22 | 46 | 961 | 961 |
> | 1 | 16-FEB-22 | 47 | 992 | 992 |
> | 1 | 17-FEB-22 | 48 | 1023 | 1023 |
> | 1 | 18-FEB-22 | 49 | 1054 | 1054 |
> | 1 | 19-FEB-22 | 50 | 1085 | 1085 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c518a2b742662a17592f2fff892a790)*

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but as usual, the problem with this approach is that the original data is huge and complicated with lots of categories and I need a date range like this for every day.

Comment: @LetterOne I fail to see that there is a problem just because the data set is "huge". Both the solutions in the answer will partition by category and will work for multiple days.